# como hacer que un GameObject funcione los EventTigger Unity

Tags: c#, unity2d

Estoy haciendo un juego en 2D para telefonos con Android.

el problema es que hice un GameObject y a este le puse una imgen de una botella, porque la idea de este GameObject es que cuando presiones la botella esta gira.

A si que lo que hice fue al GameObject colocarle desde el editor el modulo de EventTrigger para despues elegir el evento de PointerDown y pasarle otro GameObject que es el que contiene el Script con el metodo a utilizar en el PointerDown.

Pero resulta que no funciona ya que dentro del Script el metodo que mando a llamar desde el EventTigger tiene un mensaje a consola, a si que cuando presiono la imagen de la botella en mi celular no se ve ningun mensaje que se envie a la consola de Unity. Y por lo tanto me di cuenta que no esta funcionando el EventTigger.

Ya que antes de colocar el EventTigger al GameObject primero lo habia probado con una Image de la seccion UI->Canvas->Image.

A esta Imagen que hice le coloque un EventTigger y cuando presionaba la imagen esta si hacia lo que tiene que hacer mandar un mensaje a consola y hacer girar la imagen.

Pero cuando hice exactamente lo mismo,pero ahora usando un GameObject ya no funciono ni siquiera para colocar el mensaje en consola, para saber si esta responiendo el modulo que le puse desde el Unity EventTigger al GameObject

[imagen Editor Unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpOLr.jpg)

[image: codigo c sharp]

Answer (score 0):

**Resuelto**

El código queda de la siguiente manera.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ObjetoSeleccionado : MonoBehaviour
{
private bool clic = false;

private RaycastHit2D hit;
private GameObject objeto = null;

void Start()
{
}

void Update()
{
     if (Input.touchCount > 0 )
     {
        Touch tocar = Input.GetTouch(0);//Obtiene el objeto que le asigno a ese toque, que esta guardado en un arreglo.
        hit = Physics2D.GetRayIntersection(Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(tocar.position));

        if (hit.collider != null)
        {
            objeto = hit.collider.gameObject;

            if (tocar.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                clic = true;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        clic = false;
    }

    if (objeto != null)
    {
        if (clic)
        {
            objeto.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(objeto.transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, -90), Time.deltaTime * 5);
        }
        else
        {
            objeto.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(objeto.transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0), Time.deltaTime * 5);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Ahora ya con este codigo puedo detectar que GameObject (Prefabs) presiono y que solamente este Prefabs hagan la accion. Y cuando de click a otro GameObject este funcione y los otros no.